# Message top window like whatsapp

Tags: android, ios, message, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

i am trying to create a top message in my app ( iOS, Android ).
This message will be showed when a push notification arrive, but i can't make it.
**This is the code i am using.**

```
var MessageWindow = require('js/messageWindow'),
    messageWin = new MessageWindow();   
    messageWin.setLabel( "Probando mensajes en la parte superior" );
    messageWin.open();
    setTimeout(function(){  messageWin.close({opacity:0,duration:500}); },3000);
```

**And the messageWindow is:**

```
function MessageWindow() {
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
top: 0,
    height: '30%',
    width: '98%',
    borderRadius:10,
    touchEnabled:false, 
});
var messageView = Titanium.UI.createView({
    id:'messageview',
    height:'25%',
    width: '95%',
    borderRadius:10,
    backgroundColor:'#000',
    opacity:0.7,
    touchEnabled:false
});
var messageLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    id:'messagelabel',
    text:'',
    color:'#fff',
    width: '85%',
    height:'auto',
    font:{
        fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue',
        fontSize:13
    },
    textAlign:'center'
});
messageView.add(messageLabel);  
win.add(messageView);
this.setLabel = function(_text) {
    messageLabel.text = _text;
};
this.open = function(_args) {
    win.open(_args);
};
this.close = function(_args) {
    win.close(_args);
}; }module.exports = MessageWindow;
```

**Here you have a screenshot of what i want**

[image]

I've trying multiple configurations in the Window with no success..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [this widget](http://gitt.io/component/com.caffeinalab.titanium.notifications) `Ti.Notifications`

[image]